# Cluster instability due to single query inside nested field in aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am facing a weird issue in a single elasticsearch query causing cluster instability. 
I have a query with filters filters aggregation on a nested field. When I do terms query on the nested field with few values only the query works fine (no impact on cluster) however, if I add many items to the terms query the inside the nested field, then the cluster gets unstable.
I have a cluster with 4 data nodes and a master node, with 32 gb memory on each nodes.

```
    {
  "size" : 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "amount" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "user_id",
        "size" : 0
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "totalAmount" : {
          "nested" : {
            "path" : "amount"
          },
          "aggregations" : {
            "testfilters" : {
              "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "must" : {
                    "bool" : {
                      "must" : [  {
                        "terms" : {
                          **"amount.group" : [ "A1", "A2", "A4",..... "A100" ]**
                        }
                      } ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggregations" : {
                "paidAmountTotal" : {
                  "sum" : {
                    "field" : "amount.paid"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query causes cluster to become unstable.  The changes I have done is in above bold text, which is a nested field (amount.group) that I did terms aggregation on.

I have tested with adding match_all instead of values for amount.group field, though I have no issue with cluster.

How does the terms aggregation in nested field works ?
What could be cause for this ?

Comment: What type is your `amount.group` field? `text` or `keyword`?

Comment: it is string field.

Comment: ok, but analyzed or not analyzed?

Comment: {
    "group": {
        "type":     "string",
        "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
}